# Consistency between MousePosition and WindowMargins

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options

```
MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"]
```

> absolute position within the **complete screen display**

```
WindowMargins
```

> specifies the distances from each edge of the **main display screen** to each edge of the notebook window.

Those descriptions are not word to word the same but also seem to be so.

**My problem** is that I have Win7 and my *MenuBar* at the left side of the screen. `MousePosition` is counting from the screen edge while `WindowMargins` are from the *MenuBar*.

After evaluating

```
CreateDocument["TEST", 
  WindowSize -> {500, 100}, 
  WindowMargins -> {{#, Automatic}, {Automatic, #2}} & @@ MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"]]
```

I got new notebook slightly shifted. I'd like it's left top corner to appear exactly on mouse position.

[image]
(*yes, my menu bar is wide :)*)

Is this the case on Linux too?

**I would like to have** clean and stable solution so I don't have to think about where my *MenuBar* is currently positioned.

I have something in mind but it looks ugly.

---

**Edit** My idea is to create floating elements from `"Frameless"` notebooks. The problem is to put them in right position.

I was digging around lately and found out that WRI has no easy fix either. It seems they are doing, what I was about to do, in `Find & Replace` dialog:

[image]

As you can see, menu list alignment depends on where my Windows Manu bar is...

Well, maybe [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) fits now?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It creates the new notebook just at the mouse current position. I am on Windows 8.1

Comment: I have just tied with the MenuBar on the side. The issue is, that the (0, 0) coordinate is considered to be the intersection point (top-left) of the MenuBar and the rest of the screen.

Comment: if you can get the MenuBar size using Mathematica (I don't know how to do that) and adjust the mouse position values accordingly,(otherwise doing it in C++ .dll) that should work.

Comment: @SuTron you can kind of get it from `CurrentValue["ScreenArea"]` but it becomes messy for multiple screens and different layouts.

Answer (score 2):

I have no reputation to post this only as a comment, but running your code in Debian with Mathematica 10.0.2 creates the notebook with its top left corner exactly at the mouse position (tested with multiple monitors), not shifted as in your image.

Comment: Thanks for a feedback. I think it can stay as an answer. This was part of the question.